# Why does Chrome provide direct access to elements using the id

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

If I have a HTML page containing

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

I would usually access this element like so

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.innerHTML = '';
```

However in Chrome (v20) I can also access it using

```
myDiv.innerHTML = '';
```

or

```
window['myDiv'].innerHTML = '';
```

I've tested in Firefox(v13) and IE(v9) and neither support this.

Why does Chrome support this and when was this added? Are there any implications? (I'm assuming that if any variables are declared with the same name then the name will just point at the latest declaration).

I stumbled on this because I was unintentionally using window['id'] to access an element and it all worked until I tried another browser.

Comment: I can see this being convenient and improving performance by saving the need to look up the element however I'm curious if this is part of any ECMAScript standard or Google has just decided it's a nice feature.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here

Comment: @stewe Ah I searched for an existing question but couldn't find one. Cheers.